# IE11 rendering /loading icons late as compared to other browser

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, icons

I am using Angular 5 application and using SVG icons throughout site. In normal browsers like Chrome, Mozilla and Safari, icons are loading properly but in IE11 icons don't.

For that i added **svgxuse** in my pollyfill.ts file. https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse

After this change, all icons are now loading in IE11 browser but they load quite late. I mean it takes around 1-2 seconds after all content has been loaded on screen.

It is not good from user perspective. Does anyone has idea how to preload / fast load these icon in IE browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't bother, there has to be a price to pay when still using a browser released 5 years ago and which _was_ practically never updated.

Comment: It is for client. They only use IE11, Edge and Safari 11 as their primary browsers.

Comment: Well, after the first load, I can't see more significant delay in IE11 than in other browsers when viewing the git example. If I were you, I really wouldn't bother, a won second vs. a couple of days work isn't worth that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do so much .. maybe give a try to service worker (I don't know if they work in IE11) .. with `Service worker` you can load and cache images and assets ...

something like: (in your ngsw-config.js file)

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

then in your angular.cli.json file set:

```
"serviceWorker": true
```

hope it helps you!

Comment: Let me try. :) Thanx

Comment: hope it help .. but be carefull IE 11 is quite old so do a full test with service worker on it .. try the Prefetch mode